# add InvoicID new key and value in json data

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

here is my json data http://pastie.org/10988178 i want to add invoice id in particular item.like if one invoice have 3 item item than each item array add particular InvoiceID

```
"ItemDetails":[
{
"ItemId":1,
"ItemType":1,
"InvoiceDetailId":1,
"UPC":"UPCCODE1",
"SKU":"Item 1",
"Description":"Item Description",
"Qty":12,
"PunchListPart":"Item Part New if return item",
"Comment":"Comment1",
"BarCode":""
"InvoiceId":95
},
```

i want like this output

here is my code but not work

```
NSLog(@"item=%lu",[[ret_val valueForKey:@"ItemDetails" ] count]);
    NSArray *testarray=[ret_val valueForKey:@"ItemDetails" ];
    NSMutableArray *item=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0; i<[[ret_val valueForKey:@"ItemDetails" ] count]; i++) {

        NSMutableDictionary *dictValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:testarray[i]];
        [dictValues setValue:[[ret_val objectForKey:@"InvoiceId"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"InvoiceId"];
        [item addObject:dictValues];
    }
    NSLog(@"item=%@",item);
```

ret_val is my NSMutableDictionary in all json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ret_val` is your root `JSON` `Dictionary` and you want `InvoiceId` that is inside the `data` Array of your `ret_val` dictionary. So you need to access it with the dataArray also you can reduce your code using `for each` loop.

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *dataArray = [ret_val objectForKey:@"data"];
for (NSDictionary *dic in dataArray) {
     //Now loop through the `ItemDetails` array.
     NSArray *itemDetails = [dic objectForKey:@"ItemDetails"];
     for (NSDictionary *itemDic in itemDetails) {
          NSMutableDictionary *dictValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:itemDic];
          [dictValues setValue:[dic objectForKey:@"InvoiceId"] forKey:@"InvoiceId"];
          [items addObject:dictValues];
     }
}
NSLog(@"%@", items)
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x111406fb0'
 displaly this error

Comment: this line give NSArray *dataArray = [ret_val objectForKey:@"data"];

Comment: NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                               error:&error];
        data=[json objectForKey:@"data"];

Comment: data is my return value for function NSMutableDictionary *ret_val =[client1 search_read:model_name fields_arr:fields_arr domain:domain offset:offset limit:limit sort:sort]; i create this function

Comment: not display error but not get exact output.display 20 times each data

Comment: @iosdv Nice catch, actually i have copy and pasted loop code, forgot to change array name, edited answer, Also can you please remove this unnecessary comments.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like you are getting exception, put a check in Nirav Code as shown below.

```
if([NSNull null] != [dic objectForKey:@"ItemDetails"])
```

NSDictionary do not allow values to be nil, hence they are stored as null.
Thats why i am suggesting for a null check.

Hope it works.